# Multiprocessing pool with "apply_async" does nothing if executed from inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module and more partuclarly the [`Pool.apply_async()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) function.

This code works well:

```
import multiprocessing

def do():
    print("Foobar", flush=True)

with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as pool:
    for i in range(2):
        pool.apply_async(do)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The `"Foobar"` string is printed twice.

However, if I put this code in a function and then call this function, nothing happens. No error nor `"Foobar"`, the program ends silently.

```
import multiprocessing

def test():

    def do():
        print("Foobar", flush=True)

    with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as pool:
        for i in range(5):
            pool.apply_async(do)

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

test()
```

Why that? I'm using Python 3.7.3 on Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to retrieve your computation results do the following change to your code.

```
import multiprocessing

def test():

    def do():
        print("Foobar", flush=True)

    with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as pool:
        for i in range(5):
            result = pool.apply_async(do)

            result.get()

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

test()
```

You will see the reason why "nothing happens".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    test()
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 12, in test
    result.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 385, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'test.<locals>.do'
```

Python `multiprocessing.Pool` relies on the `pickle` protocol to serialize the data to be sent to the other process. The `pickle` protocol can serialize only top level functions and not nested ones.

To see what can be pickled and what cannot check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-picklable).

Comment: Thansk! But why does it fail silently if I don't call `get()`?

Comment: As you are not claiming the outcomes it will simply ignore it. The reason might be you want to execute something asynchronously no matter whether it succeeds or not. You can also check the `concurrent.futures` module which has a similar yet more clear API.

Comment: As an user, I would expect to be notified about the pickling process failing, as it's not part of my actual function. But it's ok, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Usually asynchronous calls do not cause side effects by design. Reason is async calls should not affect the execution flow of the application. It is responsibility of the developer to decide whether or not to check the outcome of the jobs which are executed asynchronously. If you don't want to block your thread waiting for results you can always use a callback function logging the results/exceptions of your submitted jobs.